# Why are Some Filter implementations Preferable for Adaptive IIRS?

Tags: filters, infinite-impulse-response, adaptive-filters

I am aware that some filter implementations such as [lattice/ladder](http://www.signal.uu.se/Staff/pd/DSP/Doc/applicat/chap6.pdf) and [SoS sections](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/Series_Parallel_Filter_Sections.html) are advantageous over high order transversal filter structures in terms of coefficient update convergence in adaptive environments but I don't understand why.

My first thought was that the transient response is altered because the number of input samples required to populate the states is reduced. But this doesn't make sense because the transient response is a characteristic of the system, not implementation.

What am I missing?

Comment: When you implement you should consider filter stability, memory, and computation load. High order filters tend to be unstable. Splitting the filter to SoS cascade stabilizes the filter. Lattice filter modifies the phase rather than the amplitude. This task is unavailable using the IIR filters

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am aware of stability, memory and load. The question is specifically asking why Lattice filters converge more quickly for adaptive filters than other implementations. What do you mean 'modifies the phase rather than amplitude'? Lattice filters can implement IIRs so I'm confused by your last sentence.

Comment: I think that you have updated your question after my answer...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why lattices converges faster.
But I know why cascades are hard to converge. Assume you want only a delayed impulse as impulse response. you have many options to achieve this intuitively. This will impose it to slower convergense and multimodality. Im also waiting for others to provide more comprehensive answer.